# How to get Widevine "DRM License Url" to play the video in ExoPlayer Android

Tags: android, azure-media-services, drm, widevine, android-drm

I have used Azure Media Service to store the encrypted videos & I am using Widevine DRM to secure the video playing on an Android App.
Exo player needs `.mdp` file URL & `Widevine License URL` in Android setup.

```
val drmCallback = HttpMediaDrmCallback(drmLicenseUrl, licenseDataSourceFactory)
```

Can someone help me to fix below issues:

1. From where will I get the `Widevine License URL` to play the video in Exo Player?
2. Can I use Azure Media Service for Widevine License delivery? If yes then please suggest documentation?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use Azure Media Services to deliver Widevine licenses.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/drm-content-protection-concept
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/drm-widevine-license-template-concept

Once a locator has been created with Widevine key license delivery, the Widevine License Url will be exposed in the DASH manifest.
[image]

It will be something like

```
https://<youramsaccount>.keydelivery.<region>.media.azure.net/Widevine/?kid=<widevinekeyid>
```

Comment: Thanks @Xavier, it is working on my device now.